# Why does building Spark sources give "object sbt is not a member of package com.typesafe"?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, apache-spark

I tried to compile the https://github.com/apache/spark project using IntelliJ IDEA with the sbt plugin on Windows.

I'm facing an error about sbt. Since I'm not familiar with sbt, I don't know how to fix it.

The error messages are as follows:

```
[info] Loading project definition from F:\codeReading\sbtt\spark-master\project
[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to F:\codeReading\sbtt\spark-master\project\target\scala-2.10\sbt-0.13\classes...
[error] F:\codeReading\sbtt\spark-master\project\SparkBuild.scala:26: object sbt is not a member of package com.typesafe
[error] import com.typesafe.sbt.pom.{PomBuild, SbtPomKeys}
[error]                     ^
[error] F:\codeReading\sbtt\spark-master\project\SparkBuild.scala:51: not found: type PomBuild
[error] object SparkBuild extends PomBuild {
[error]                           ^
[error] F:\codeReading\sbtt\spark-master\project\SparkBuild.scala:118: not found: value SbtPomKeys
[error]     otherResolvers <<= SbtPomKeys.mvnLocalRepository(dotM2 => Seq(Resolver.file("dotM2", dotM2))),
[error]                        ^
[error] F:\codeReading\sbtt\spark-master\project\SparkBuild.scala:178: value projectDefinitions is not a member of AnyRef
[error]     super.projectDefinitions(baseDirectory).map { x =>
[error]           ^
[error] four errors found
[error] (plugins/compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

---

Comment: How did you execute the compilation in IDEA? Is this upon importing the project to IDEA?

Comment: I downloaded the spark-master.zip from github/apache/spark, unzipped it, and then imported the unzipped project with sbt rather maven. My operations in Intellij-idea (Windows XP OS) are: File-> Import project->choose the spark-master directory -> Select 'Import Project from External model'->select 'SBT project'->Next->Finish

Comment: Yes, I imported the project using IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

Spark is built with Maven. The SBT build is only a convenience. You will have far better results importing it as a Maven project.

Comment: You are right. I've tried to compile Spark using maven, and I made it.

Comment: Ouch, I've missed that switch. When did they move to maven? I remember 1.0.0 was still with sbt *and* maven. Thanks.

Comment: The version I imported with maven is 1.0.0. I failed in both 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 with SBT.

Comment: There's still an SBT build exported from Maven, mind. I think that may even be post-1.0, but it's been in master for a few weeks. I assumed the OP is building from master.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like IDEA doesn't like project references to git projects that the Spark build definition uses for [sbt-pom-reader](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pom-reader).

It's showed up when I ran `sbt` within the cloned project:

```
➜  spark git:(master) ✗ xsbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/oss/spark/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/staging/ec3aa8f39111944cc5f2/sbt-pom-reader/project
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/oss/spark/project
[info] Set current project to spark-parent (in build file:/Users/jacek/oss/spark/)
>
```

You can see the project reference to the git project of sbt-pom-reader when accessing the `plugins` project for which the reference is defined:

```
> reload plugins
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/oss/spark/project/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/oss/spark/project/project/}project-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/staging/ec3aa8f39111944cc5f2/sbt-pom-reader/project
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/staging/ec3aa8f39111944cc5f2/sbt-pom-reader/project/}sbt-pom-reader-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/oss/spark/project
> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/oss/spark/project/
[info]   * plugins
[info]     spark-style
[info] In https://github.com/ScrapCodes/sbt-pom-reader.git
[info]     sbt-pom-reader
```

A solution *could be* executing `sbt gen-idea` to generate the project files for IDEA. It's just a guess, though.