# SBT gives java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to run spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm trying to compile spark with sbt 1.7.2 on a Linux machine which system is CentOs6.

When I try to run clean command:
`./build/sbt clean`

I get the following output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.net.util.URLUtil.urlNoFragString(URLUtil.java:50)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:526)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(URLClassPath.java:498)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:252)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:406)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:406)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:406)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:406)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at sbt.internal.XMainConfiguration.run(XMainConfiguration.java:51)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:46)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$run$1(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:176)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$apply$1(Launch.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:159)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:73)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] [launcher] error during sbt launcher: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It also happened when I use sbt 1.7.3, But it can success clean and compile spark when I use sbt 1.6.2.

What should I check first? I'd really appreciate any advice anyone can offer.

Comment: If you want to do `clean` can you manually delete folder (folders) `target`?

Comment: Yes, I can. But the problem doesn't just arise when do clean. Seems like sbt launch problem?

Comment: Something like that. One can debug what exactly is null. Just in case, bug tracker is here https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues

Comment: Could you share your `build.sbt`?

Comment: By "compiling spark" do you mean compiling your project using spark, not spark itself? (Spark [itself](https://github.com/apache/spark) seems to be built with maven.)

Comment: No，I mean spark itself. Spark support build with sbt. Its build.sbt(name SparkBuild.scala) is in the "project" directory of SPARK.

Comment: I'll try this tracker. Thanks~

Comment: Ah ok. Good to know. I'll try to reproduce then.

Comment: Can't reproduce. But I'm on Ubuntu. How do you check what sbt version you use while building a project? By running `sbt-1.6.2/bin/sbt clean compile` vs. `sbt-1.7.3/bin/sbt clean compile`? https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/73ae5e54fb0275fa362aef94f24e9b3b But this is **sbt script version**, not actual **project sbt version** that a project is built with. The latter is specified in `project/build.properties`. Currently it's 1.8.0. Did you change `sbt.version` to 1.6.2 vs. 1.7.3 in `project/build.properties`? https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/d734abc3697afcc44ab0e0a3f10a1513

Comment: Also what JDK do you use? Mine is `graalvm-ee-java8-19.3.0` `java version "1.8.0_231"` `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)` `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit GraalVM EE 19.3.0 (build 25.231-b11-jvmci-19.3-b05, mixed mode)`. For me firstly during compilation it didn't find `javac`. Mine is in `graalvm-ee-java8-19.3.0/bin/` while it was looking in `graalvm-ee-java8-19.3.0/jre/bin/`. So I had to create a symbolic link. Then compilation was successful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990904/why-does-building-spark-sources-give-object-sbt-is-not-a-member-of-package-com

Comment: First of all, sbt-1.8.0 can successful build. So we update sbt version to 1.8.0 yesterday. And my JDK is Zulu 8.62.0.19-CA-linux64 openjdk version "1.8.0_332"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.62.0.19-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_332-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.62.0.19-CA-linux64) (build 25.332-b09, mixed mode).

Comment: I was going to propose you to debug sbt a little to see what exactly is null. One can clone https://github.com/sbt/sbt , put to subroject `client` (`sbt-client`, `sbtClientProj`) the following class https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/28ed91b14aa114b687536c3a0390d9b5 and debug in IDE setting up a breakpoint for `NullPointerException`. But IntelliJ Idea seems not to be able to build `sbt` because of code generation https://www.scala-sbt.org/contraband/ It seems only sbt can build sbt (`sbtClientProj/runMain MyMain`), so I haven't figured out how to debug.

Comment: From your stack trace I have suspection that one of `urls` is null https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#L82 But if you resolved your issue with upgrading sbt to script version `1.8.0`, the better. Great, congrats.

Comment: I want to try to figure out the cause of the null pointer exception to rule out an operational problem. Thanks for your advice and reply. I'll give it a try~

Comment: I added an answer with advices how to debug sbt code.

Answer (score 0):

Several advices how to debug Spark and sbt.

### **How to build Spark in IntelliJ.**

Clone https://github.com/apache/spark , open it in IntelliJ as sbt project.

I had to execute `sbt compile` and re-open the project before I can run my code in IntelliJ (I had an error `object SqlBaseParser is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser` before that). For example I can put the following object in `sql/core/src/main/scala` and run/debug it in IntelliJ

```scala
// scalastyle:off
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}

object MyMain extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("SparkTestApp")
    .getOrCreate()

  case class Person(id: Long, name: String)

  import spark.implicits._

  val df: Dataset[Person] = spark.range(10).map(i => Person(i, i.toString))

  df.show()

//+---+----+
//| id|name|
//+---+----+
//|  0|   0|
//|  1|   1|
//|  2|   2|
//|  3|   3|
//|  4|   4|
//|  5|   5|
//|  6|   6|
//|  7|   7|
//|  8|   8|
//|  9|   9|
//+---+----+

}
```

I also pressed `Run npm install`, `Load Maven project` when these pop-up windows appeared but I haven't noticed the difference.

Also once I had to keep in `Project Structure` in `sql/catalyst/target/scala-2.12/src_managed` only one source root `sql/catalyst/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main` (and not `sql/catalyst/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main/antlr4`). I had errors like `SqlBaseLexer is already defined as class SqlBaseLexer` before that.

Build Apache Spark Source Code with IntelliJ IDEA: https://yujheli-wordpress-com.translate.goog/2020/03/26/build-apache-spark-source-code-with-intellij-idea/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=uk&_x_tr_pto=wapp (original in Chinese: https://yujheli.wordpress.com/2020/03/26/build-apache-spark-source-code-with-intellij-idea/ )

[Why does building Spark sources give "object sbt is not a member of package com.typesafe"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990904/why-does-building-spark-sources-give-object-sbt-is-not-a-member-of-package-com)

### **How to build sbt in IntelliJ.**

sbt itself is tricky https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/SowhatswrongwithSBT.html and building it is a little tricky too.

Clone https://github.com/sbt/sbt , open it in IntelliJ. Let's try to run the previous Spark code using this cloned sbt.

sbt seems to be not intended to run in a specified directory. I put the following object in `client/src/main/scala`

```scala
object MyClient extends App {
  System.setProperty("user.dir", "../spark")
  sbt.client.Client.main(Array("sql/runMain MyMain"))
}
```

(Generally, mutating the system property `user.dir` is not recommended: [How to use "cd" command using Java runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884681/how-to-use-cd-command-using-java-runtime))

I had to execute `sbt compile` firstly (this includes the command `sbt generateContrabands` --- sbt uses sbt plugin `sbt-contraband` (`ContrabandPlugin`, `JsonCodecPlugin`), formerly `sbt-datatype`, for code generation: https://github.com/sbt/contraband https://www.scala-sbt.org/contraband/ https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Datatype.html https://github.com/eed3si9n/gigahorse/tree/develop/core/src/main/contraband). I had error `not found: value ScalaKeywords` before that.

Next error is `type ExcludeItem is not a member of package sbt.internal.bsp`. You can just remove in `protocol/src/main/contraband-scala/sbt/internal/bsp/codec` the files `ExcludeItemFormats.scala`, `ExcludesItemFormats.scala`, `ExcludesParamsFormats.scala`, `ExcludesResultFormats.scala`. They are outdated auto-generated files. You can check that if you remove the content of directory `protocol/src/main/contraband-scala` (this is a root for auto-generated sources) and execute `sbt generateContrabands` all the files except these four will be restored. For some reason these files didn't confuse sbt but confuse IntelliJ.

Now, while running, `MyClient` produces

```scala
//[info] +---+----+
//[info] | id|name|
//[info] +---+----+
//[info] |  0|   0|
//[info] |  1|   1|
//[info] |  2|   2|
//[info] |  3|   3|
//[info] |  4|   4|
//[info] |  5|   5|
//[info] |  6|   6|
//[info] |  7|   7|
//[info] |  8|   8|
//[info] |  9|   9|
//[info] +---+----+
```

`sbt.client.Client` is called the thin client. Alternatively, you can publish it locally and use as a dependency

*build.sbt* (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.8.0/build.sbt#L1160)

```scala
lazy val sbtClientProj = (project in file("client"))
  .enablePlugins(NativeImagePlugin)
  .dependsOn(commandProj)
  .settings(
    commonBaseSettings,
    scalaVersion := "2.12.11",
    publish / skip := false, // change true to false
    name := "sbt-client",
    .......
```

`sbt publishLocal`

A new project:

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.12.17"

// ~/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt-client/1.8.1-SNAPSHOT/jars/sbt-client.jar
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-sbt" % "sbt-client" % "1.8.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

*src/main/scala/Main.scala*

```scala
object Main extends App {
  System.setProperty("user.dir", "../spark")
  sbt.client.Client.main(Array("sql/runMain MyMain"))
  
  //[info] +---+----+
  //[info] | id|name|
  //[info] +---+----+
  //[info] |  0|   0|
  //[info] |  1|   1|
  //[info] |  2|   2|
  //[info] |  3|   3|
  //[info] |  4|   4|
  //[info] |  5|   5|
  //[info] |  6|   6|
  //[info] |  7|   7|
  //[info] |  8|   8|
  //[info] |  9|   9|
  //[info] +---+----+
}
```

But the thin client is not how sbt normally runs. `sbt.xMain` from your stack trace is from https://github.com/sbt/sbt . It's here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.8.x/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Main.scala#L44 But `xsbt.boot.Boot` from the stack trace is not from this repo, it's from https://github.com/sbt/launcher , namely https://github.com/sbt/launcher/blob/1.x/launcher-implementation/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Boot.scala

The thing is that sbt runs in two steps. The sbt executable (usually downloaded from https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html#universal-packages) is a shell script, firstly it runs `sbt-launch.jar` (the object `xsbt.boot.Boot`)

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.8.0/sbt#L507-L512

```bash
execRunner "$java_cmd" \
  "${java_args[@]}" \
  "${sbt_options[@]}" \
  -jar "$sbt_jar" \
  "${sbt_commands[@]}" \
  "${residual_args[@]}"
```

and secondly the latter reflectively calls sbt (the class `sbt.xMain`)

https://github.com/sbt/launcher/blob/v1.4.1/launcher-implementation/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Launch.scala#L147-L149

```scala
val main = appProvider.newMain()
try {
  withContextLoader(appProvider.loader)(main.run(appConfig))
```

https://github.com/sbt/launcher/blob/v1.4.1/launcher-implementation/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Launch.scala#L496

```scala
// implementation of the above appProvider.newMain()
else if (AppMainClass.isAssignableFrom(entryPoint)) mainClass.newInstance
```

https://github.com/sbt/launcher/blob/v1.4.1/launcher-implementation/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/PlainApplication.scala#L13

```scala
// implementation of the above main.run(appConfig)
mainMethod.invoke(null, configuration.arguments).asInstanceOf[xsbti.Exit]
```

Then `xMain#run` via `XMainConfiguration#run` reflectively calls `xMain.run`

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.8.0/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Main.scala#L44-L47

```scala
class xMain extends xsbti.AppMain {
  def run(configuration: xsbti.AppConfiguration): xsbti.MainResult =
    new XMainConfiguration().run("xMain", configuration)
}
```

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.8.0/main/src/main/java/sbt/internal/XMainConfiguration.java#L51-L57

```scala
Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass("sbt." + moduleName + "$");
Object instance = clazz.getField("MODULE$").get(null);
Method runMethod = clazz.getMethod("run", xsbti.AppConfiguration.class);
try {
  .....
  return (xsbti.MainResult) runMethod.invoke(instance, updatedConfiguration);
```

Then it downloads and runs necessary version of Scala (specified in a `build.sbt`) and necessary version of the rest of sbt (specified in a `project/build.properties`).

### **What is the launcher.**

Let's consider a helloworld for the launcher.

The launcher consists of a library (interfaces)

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/launcher-interface

https://github.com/sbt/launcher/tree/1.x/launcher-interface

and the launcher runnable jar

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/launcher

https://github.com/sbt/launcher/tree/1.x/launcher-implementation/src

Create a project (depending on launcher interfaces at compile tome)

*build.sbt*

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "scalademo",
    organization := "com.example",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.10",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scala-sbt" % "launcher-interface" % "1.4.1" % Provided,
    ),
  )
```

*src/main/scala/mypackage/Main.scala* (this class will be an entry point while working with the launcher)

```scala
package mypackage

import xsbti.{AppConfiguration, AppMain, Exit, MainResult}

class Main extends AppMain {
  def run(configuration: AppConfiguration): MainResult = {
    val scalaVersion = configuration.provider.scalaProvider.version

    println(s"Hello, World! Running Scala $scalaVersion")
    configuration.arguments.foreach(println)

    new Exit {
      override val code: Int = 0
    }
  }
}
```

Do `sbt publishLocal`. The project jar will be published at `~/.ivy2/local/com.example/scalademo_2.13/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/scalademo_2.13.jar`

Download launcher runnable jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/launcher/1.4.1/launcher-1.4.1.jar

Create launcher configuration

*my.app.configuration*

```
[scala]
  version: 2.13.10
[app]
  org: com.example
  name: scalademo
  version: 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
  class: mypackage.Main
  cross-versioned: binary
[repositories]
  local
  maven-central
[boot]
  directory: ${user.home}/.myapp/boot
```

Then command `java -jar launcher-1.4.1.jar @my.app.configuration a b c` produces

```scala
//Hello world! Running Scala 2.13.10
//a
//b
//c
```

There appeared files

```
~/.myapp/boot/scala-2.13.10/com.example/scalademo/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
  scalademo_2.13.jar
  scala-library-2.13.10.jar
~/.myapp/boot/scala-2.13.10/lib
  java-diff-utils-4.12.jar
  jna-5.9.0.jar
  jline-3.21.0.jar
  scala-library.jar
  scala-compiler.jar
  scala-reflect.jar
```

So launcher helps to run application in environments with only Java installed (Scala is not necessary), Ivy dependency resolution will be used. There are features to handle return codes, reboot application with a different Scala version, launch servers etc.

Alternatively, any of the following commands can be used

```
java -Dsbt.boot.properties=my.app.configuration -jar launcher-1.4.1.jar
java -jar launcher-repacked.jar      # put my.app.configuration to sbt/sbt.boot.properties/ and repack the jar
```

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Launcher-Getting-Started.html

### **How to run sbt with the launcher.**

Sbt https://github.com/sbt/sbt uses sbt plugin `SbtLauncherPlugin` https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.8.0/project/SbtLauncherPlugin.scala so that from the raw launcher `launcher`

https://github.com/sbt/launcher/tree/1.x/launcher-implementation/src

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/launcher

it builds `sbt-launch`

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/tree/v1.8.0/launch

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch

Basically, `sbt-launch` is different from `launcher` in having default config `sbt.boot.properties` injected.

If we'd like to run sbt with the launcher then we should find a way to specify a working directory for sbt (similarly to how we did this while working with thin client).

Working directory can be set either 1) in `sbt.xMain` (`sbt`) or 2) in `xsbt.boot.Boot` (`sbt-launcher`).

`1)` Make `sbt.xMain` non-final so that it can be extended

```scala
/*final*/ class xMain extends xsbti.AppMain { 
...........
```

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.8.0/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Main.scala#L44

Put a new class to `main/src/main/scala` (a launcher-style entry point)

```scala
import sbt.xMain
import xsbti.{ AppConfiguration, AppProvider, MainResult }
import java.io.File

class MyXMain extends xMain {
  override def run(configuration: AppConfiguration): MainResult = {
    val args = configuration.arguments

    val (dir, rest) =
      if (args.length >= 1 && args(0).startsWith("dir=")) {
        (
          Some(args(0).stripPrefix("dir=")),
          args.drop(1)
        )
      } else {
        (None, args)
      }

    dir.foreach { dir =>
      System.setProperty("user.dir", dir)
    }

    // xMain.run(new AppConfiguration { // not ok
    // new xMain().run(new AppConfiguration { // not ok
    super[xMain].run(new AppConfiguration { // ok
      override val arguments: Array[String] = rest
      override val baseDirectory: File =
        dir.map(new File(_)).getOrElse(configuration.baseDirectory)
      override val provider: AppProvider = configuration.provider
    })
  }
}
```

`sbt publishLocal`

*my.sbt.configuration*

```
[scala]
  version: auto
  #version: 2.12.17
[app]
  org: org.scala-sbt
  name: sbt
  #name: main  # not ok
  version: 1.8.1-SNAPSHOT
  class: MyXMain
  #class: sbt.xMain
  components: xsbti,extra
  cross-versioned: false
  #cross-versioned: binary
[repositories]
  local
  maven-central
[boot]
  directory: ${user.home}/.mysbt/boot
[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${user.home}/.ivy2
```

A command:

`java -jar launcher-1.4.1.jar @my.sbt.configuration dir=/path_to_spark/spark "sql/runMain MyMain"`

or

`java -jar sbt-launch.jar @my.sbt.configuration dir=/path_to_spark/spark "sql/runMain MyMain"`

```scala
//[info] +---+----+
//[info] | id|name|
//[info] +---+----+
//[info] |  0|   0|
//[info] |  1|   1|
//[info] |  2|   2|
//[info] |  3|   3|
//[info] |  4|   4|
//[info] |  5|   5|
//[info] |  6|   6|
//[info] |  7|   7|
//[info] |  8|   8|
//[info] |  9|   9|
//[info] +---+----+
```

(`sbt-launch.jar` is taken from `~/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/1.8.1-SNAPSHOT/jars` or just https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch since we haven't modified launcher yet)

I had to copy `scalastyle-config.xml` from `spark`, otherwise it wasn't found.

Still I have warnings `fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent ...) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).`

`2)`

*project/Dependencies.scala* (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.8.0/project/Dependencies.scala#L25)

```scala
val launcherVersion = "1.4.2-SNAPSHOT" // modified
```

Clone https://github.com/sbt/launcher and make the following changes

*build.sbt* (https://github.com/sbt/launcher/blob/v1.4.1/build.sbt#L11)

```scala
ThisBuild / version := {
  val orig = (ThisBuild / version).value
  if (orig.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) "1.4.2-SNAPSHOT" // modified
  else orig
}
```

*launcher-implementation/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Launch.scala*
(https://github.com/sbt/launcher/blob/v1.4.1/launcher-implementation/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Launch.scala#L17
[#L21](https://github.com/sbt/launcher/blob/v1.4.1/launcher-implementation/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Launch.scala#L21))

```scala
class LauncherArguments(
    val args: List[String],
    val isLocate: Boolean,
    val isExportRt: Boolean,
    val dir: Option[String] = None // added
)

object Launch {
  def apply(arguments: LauncherArguments): Option[Int] =
    apply((new File(arguments.dir.getOrElse(""))).getAbsoluteFile, arguments) // modified

  .............
```

*launcher-implementation/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Boot.scala* (https://github.com/sbt/launcher/blob/v1.4.1/launcher-implementation/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Boot.scala#L41-L67)

```scala
  def parseArgs(args: Array[String]): LauncherArguments = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def parse(
        args: List[String],
        isLocate: Boolean,
        isExportRt: Boolean,
        remaining: List[String],
        dir: Option[String] // added
    ): LauncherArguments =
      args match {
        ...................
        case "--locate" :: rest        => parse(rest, true, isExportRt, remaining, dir) // modified
        case "--export-rt" :: rest     => parse(rest, isLocate, true, remaining, dir) // modified

          // added
        case "--mydir" :: next :: rest => parse(rest, isLocate, isExportRt, remaining, Some(next))

        case next :: rest              => parse(rest, isLocate, isExportRt, next :: remaining, dir) // modified
        case Nil                       => new LauncherArguments(remaining.reverse, isLocate, isExportRt, dir) // modified
      }
    parse(args.toList, false, false, Nil, None)
  }
```

sbt-launcher: `sbt publishLocal`

sbt: `sbt publishLocal`

*my.sbt.configuration*

```
[scala]
  version: auto
[app]
  org: org.scala-sbt
  name: sbt
  version: 1.8.1-SNAPSHOT
  #class: MyXMain
  class: sbt.xMain
  components: xsbti,extra
  cross-versioned: false
[repositories]
  local
  maven-central
[boot]
  directory: ${user.home}/.mysbt/boot
[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${user.home}/.ivy2
```

A command:

`java -jar launcher-1.4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar @my.sbt.configuration --mydir /path_to_spark/spark "sql/runMain MyMain"`

or

`java -jar sbt-launch.jar @my.sbt.configuration --mydir /path_to_spark/spark "sql/runMain MyMain"`

or

`java -jar sbt-launch.jar --mydir /path_to_spark/spark "sql/runMain MyMain"` (using default `sbt.boot.properties` rather than `my.sbt.configuration`)

(we're using modified `launcher` or new `sbt-launch` using this modified `launcher`).

Alternatively, we can specify "program arguments" in "Run configuration" for `xsbt.boot.Boot` in IntelliJ

`@/path_to_sbt_config/my.sbt.configuration --mydir /path_to_spark/spark "sql/runMain MyMain"`

Also it's possible to specify working directory `/path_to_spark/spark` in "Run configuration" in IntelliJ. Then remaining "program arguments" are

`@/path_to_sbt_config/my.sbt.configuration "sql/runMain MyMain"`

I tried to use `"org.scala-sbt" % "launcher" % "1.4.2-SNAPSHOT"` or `"org.scala-sbt" % "sbt-launch" % "1.8.1-SNAPSHOT"` as a dependency but got `No RuntimeVisibleAnnotations in classfile with ScalaSignature attribute: class Boot`.

### **Your setting.**

So we can run/debug sbt-launcher code in  IntelliJ and/or with `println`s and run/debug sbt code with `println`s (because there is no runnable object).

From your stack trace I have suspection that one of classloader `urls` is null

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#L82

Maybe you can add to `sbt.xMain#run` or `MyXMain#run` something like

```scala
var cl = getClass.getClassLoader
while (cl != null) {
  println(s"classloader: ${cl.getClass.getName}")
  cl match {
    case cl: URLClassLoader =>
      println("classloader urls:")
      cl.getURLs.foreach(println)
    case _ =>
      println("not URLClassLoader")
  }
  cl = cl.getParent
}
```

in order to see what url is null.

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Developers-Guide.html

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.8.x/DEVELOPING.md

Comment: `No RuntimeVisibleAnnotations in classfile with ScalaSignature attribute: class DefaultFormats` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73975781/how-to-resolve-scalac-error-assertion-failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150776/debugging-scala-code-with-simple-build-tool-sbt-and-intellij

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html#debug_scala_code

Comment: https://www.beyondthelines.net/computing/understanding-sbt/